# R Programming - convert numeric to MM:SS

Tags: r, numeric

This may be a silly question, but I can't find anything on this.

I have a numeric value that represents seconds. How can I convert it to MM:SS

For example

My number is 96

Represented in MM:SS it should be 01:36.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
x<-96
sprintf("%02d:%02d",x%/%60,x%%60)
#[1] "01:36"
```

Answer (score 9):

The `%/%` ([integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers)) and `%%` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) operators are your friends:

```
x <- 96
paste(x %/% 60, x %% 60, sep = ":")
```

which gives

```
> paste(x %/% 60, x %% 60, sep = ":")
[1] "1:36"
```

Here it is in a function:

```
d2ms <- function(x) {
  paste(x %/% 60, x %% 60, sep = ":")
}

> xx <- c(120, 96, 45, 30)
> d2ms(xx)
[1] "2:0"  "1:36" "0:45" "0:30"
```

Which shows we need a little help to get exactly the format you need; see `?sprint` for ways to format numbers [as characters] with leading 0s etc:

```
d2ms <- function(x) {
  sprintf("%02d:%02d", x %/%60, x %% 60)
}

> d2ms(xx)
[1] "02:00" "01:36" "00:45" "00:30"
```

Note that the `:` in the string above is a literal, the `%xxy` bits are the formats for the values specified in the next two arguments and include formatting details for the number of zeros to pad (i.e. pad with zeroes until number uses two digits.) The template for this usage here is:

`%[flag][width]specifier`,

where here we used:

- `0` as the flag --- pad with `0`s
- width was `2`, we want MM or SS
- specifier was `d` for integers (could also have been `i`)

Whether you need that or not is up to your end use case.

These operators are quite useful for these sorts of operations; another example would be converting from degrees, minutes, seconds notation to decimal degrees for spatial coordinates.

Comment: I didn't so stop with the accusations; I submitted my answer, realised it wasn't 100% exactly what the OP wanted so did the logical thing and sprintf-ed the output. `sprintf()` is hardly so weirdly arcane part of R or computing for outputting strings that it's impossible two people'd come up with the same solution.

Comment: I actually don't give a fig if you're OK with it or not; I didn't copy your answer (are we still in school?), I just realised as I submitted the Answer that it wasn't quite right, and set about rectifying that minor point.

Comment: Ok, I worded it very badly. I should have just said: "Hey, your edit is basically my answer" or anything at all. I deleted my comments. Sorry for having been rude. Don't really think you voluntarily copied my answer of course. Was just surprised to see my answer replicated and commented without thinking that much. Hope it clarifies a little.